# How to Convert UTC time to local time In Swift 3?

Tags: swift

Here , I want to convert the UTC time to Local time formate in swift 3, but i'am not able to convert it. Please help me for this

`let StrDate = "2018-03-06T13:32:57 +05:30"` I want to Convert this Date into local time format.

```
 func convertStringDateFormateUTC(strDate: String,
     strCurrentFormateType:String, strFormateType:String) -> String {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = strCurrentFormateType
            var strNewdate = NSDate()
            strNewdate = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)! as NSDate
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = strFormateType;
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
            return dateFormatter.string(from: strNewdate as Date)
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3.0 : Convert server UTC time to local time and visa-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803349/swift-3-0-convert-server-utc-time-to-local-time-and-visa-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TimeZone.current` to detect local timezone and apply it.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
// initially set the format based on your datepicker date
var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String { return TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? "UTC" }
//print(localTimeZoneAbbreviation)
formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: localTimeZoneAbbreviation)
// convert your string to date
let yourDate = formatter.date(from: strDate)
//then again set the date format which type of output you need
```

In your function  :

```
func convertStringDateFormateUTC(strDate: String,
                                 strCurrentFormateType:String, strFormateType:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = strCurrentFormateType

    var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String { return TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? "UTC" }
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: localTimeZoneAbbreviation)

    var strNewdate = NSDate()
    strNewdate = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)! as NSDate
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = strFormateType;
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
    return dateFormatter.string(from: strNewdate as Date)
}
```

Comment: When i calculate time it shows it shows 1 hour extra ex. 6:00:00 +5:30 UTC time then I get 12:30 but i think i get 11:30 . Is it Right or not ?

Comment: Its right.  6:00:00 +5:30 UTC means  12:30 because in UTC its adds  +5:30 hr