# UIDatePicker returns current date not selected date

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker`, which I print the selected date as per the code below. However, it doesn't print the selected date, only the current date.

```
@objc func setupDiscoverButton() {

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FirstTableViewCell

    // Date
    let sessionDate = cell.datePicker.date

    print("date: \(sessionDate)")
}
```

This is where I make definitions for my `UIDatePicker`.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FirstTableViewCell

    // Date & time picker
    cell.datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
    cell.datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    // Discover button
    cell.discoverButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setupDiscoverButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Share you date picker code

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish I've added this

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish It is made in Storyboard - do I have to implement other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get change of DatePicker listen to `datePickerChanged`

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(picker:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

So your cell will be

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FirstTableViewCell

    // Date & time picker
    cell.datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
    cell.datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone.current
cell.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(picker:)), for: .valueChanged)

    // Discover button
    cell.discoverButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setupDiscoverButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

  @objc func datePickerChanged(picker: UIDatePicker) {
        print(picker.date)
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks :) - and do you know how I change the time printed to the user's location's time zone, not the standard UTC?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803349/swift-3-0-convert-server-utc-time-to-local-time-and-visa-versa/42811162 about Date

Comment: But I wouldn't want to use `DateFormatter` since I want to keep the date as a `Date`, not a `String` - I tried `datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone.current`, but that's not working.

Comment: `datePicker.locale = Locale.current`

Comment: what you need from date its UTC are you need in which format? what is print result and what your target result

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes You do want a DateFormatter. Keep the `Date`. But use a DateFormatter whenever you wish to show the `Date` to the user.

Comment: @rmaddy But would I be able to store the Date in the user's time zone?

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes `Date` doesn't have a timezone. Just store the date as-is. No need to do any conversion. You might find http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html helpful to better understand Date.